# Aborting AJAX request on the server side (PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bash

I am trying to write a function in PHP that will be called through an AJAX request. The function will run some bash command and be aborted on the server side if the visitor aborts the AJAX request.

So far I have written the code below. It makes sure that the bash command does not run for longer than 5 minutes, and it stops when the command returns "yes" or "no". But I have two problems:

- if the AJAX request is cancelled on the client side (using `MyXHR.abort()` in Java Script), the `connection_status() == CONNECTION_NORMAL` check still returns `true`. How can I make it break?
- when the AJAX request is cancelled, I'd like to kill the process that has been launched with the bash command to save computing power. Is it possible to do that?

_

```
function my_function($post) {

        $command = 'my_bash_command';
        $output_file = 'output.txt';
        exec('bash -c "exec nohup setsid ' . $command . ' > '.$output_file .' 2>&1 &"');

        $phpTimeoutCountdown=5*60; // 5 minutes max
        while($phpTimeoutCountdown>0){
            if(connection_status() == CONNECTION_NORMAL){
                if(file_exists($output_file )){
                    $output_value=exec('tail -n 1 '.$output_file );
                    if(in_array($output_value,["yes","no"])){
                        return($output_value);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                return(false);  
                // If connection is broken, then it should return false
                // in order to allow a new AJAX request to start being executed in PHP
            }
            sleep(1);  // Sleep for 1 second
            $phpTimeoutCountdown--;
        }
}
```

Comment: when you abort a ajax connection the php will continue to execute your code, the php doesn't know you aborted the ajax

Comment: Then what does the `connection_status()` function do in PHP?

Comment: The connection_status() function returns the current connection status.

Comment: So if the AJAX request is aborted, connection_status() would indicate that, right?